# Is there something wrong with this Filter function code in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to filer the "ToothGrowth" dataset by "dose" of the "supp" in R but I am receiving the below mentioned error.

CODE:

```
install.packages("dplyr")
data("ToothGrowth")
View(ToothGrowth)
filtered_tg <- filter(ToothGrowth, dose==0.5)
View (filtered_tg)
```

ERROR:

> Error in filter(ToothGrowth, dose == 0.5) : object 'dose' not found
> View (filtered_tg)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `library(dplyr)` after `install.packages("dplyr")`.

Comment: or use `dplyr::filter()`

Comment: thanks a ton
 I can't believe I overlooked this basic part!